# Django view doesn't receive Json data?

Tags: python, django, python-requests

Using a simple Python script, i want to send a request, with Python-Requests, to a Django view. The Django view should receive the json data inside the request and should print it to my console; here is what i tried:

This is how i send the request:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myview/view'
client = requests.session()   
csrftoken = requests.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']
data = json.dumps({'data': 'test-value'})
header = {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
cookies = {'csrftoken': csrftoken}
resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header, cookies=cookies)
```

And this is how the Django view receives it:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        print(data)
        print('received.')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response
```

The problem with my current code is that `print(data)` will throw the following output:

```
None
received.
[06/Jan/2020 21:23:57] "POST /myview/view HTTP/1.1" 200 64
```

So, instead of printing `test-value`, it prints nothing. I don't understand whether the error is in my Django view or in how i'm sending the request. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your request, and entirely caused by this line:

```
data = json.dumps({'data': 'test-value'})
```

You simply want

```
data = {'data': 'test-value'}
```

The POST data should be sent as a simple dictionary, not a JSON string - see the documentation and example [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/).

Comment: Fair enough! I'm getting the correct output now. Going through the docs right now, thank you!